# Entering 'then' function of '$q.all' before 'then' of single promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have this code:

```
function first() {
    let promises = two(arg);
    $q.all(promises).then(() => {
        console.log("all promises");
    });
}

function two(arg) {
    let promises = [];
    arg.forEach((ar) => {
        let promise = funcThatReturnPromise(ar).then(() => {
            console.log("single promise");
        });
        promises.push(promise);
    });
    return promises;
}
```

I want that all of the `"single promise"` will be printed before the `"all promises"` but actually the `"all promises"` prints before some of the  `"single promise"`.

How can I force it that all of the `"single promise"` will printed before the `"all promises"`?

I tried to find a solution but I couldn't find the reason for this.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested your code and cannot seem to replicate your issue. Every `"single promise"` will be printed out before the final `"all promises"` as should be the expected behavior.
If one of the promises gets rejected, $q.all's `then` branch will not run.
My testing code was:

```
const fakePromise = () => {
    var deferred = this.$q.defer();
    this.$timeout(() => {
        deferred.resolve();
    }, Math.random() * 100);
    return deferred.promise;
}

const two = (arg) => {
    let promises = [];
    arg.forEach((ar) => {
        let promise = fakePromise().then(() => {
            console.log("single promise");
        });
        promises.push(promise);
    });
    return promises;
}
const first = () => {
    let promises = two(Array(2000).fill('x'));
    this.$q.all(promises).then(() => {
        console.log("all promises");
    });
};

first();
```

Maybe if you have some other example, I could help more.